# Interpolation to account for heaping effect in mortality time series for regression analysis

Tags: time-series, interpolation, mortality

I am trying to estimate the relationship between daily temperature and daily number of deaths (from all causes) for a specific location using time series regression. More specifically, using a DLNM, i.e. a distributed lag non-linear model for an over-dispersed Poisson distribution (Gasparrini et al, [2010](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.3940) and [2011](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v043i08)).

The daily time series data over the 14 year period consists of: number of deaths, number of births, number of inward migrations, number of outward migrations, temperature.

I also have the population size at the start of the 14 year period (~ 73,000 individuals). For each day I have then calculated the change in population size as births + inward migrations - deaths - outward migrations and recalculated population size for each day. Population size after 14 years is ~ 80,000.

The model for daily number of deaths will as a minimum include terms for temperature (fitted by spline, and including a spline for the lag term too), seasonality and long-term trend (fitted by spline) , rain (continous var) and population size (continous var). The maximum lag will likely be between 20 and 30 days, based on reports in the literature.

The location is a rural district in a low income country. Data is only collected once or twice a year during fieldwork, which involves visiting and interviewing households. Dates of death, birth, in and out migration are likely to be noisy due to recall problems. If a person couldn't remember the date of the event, questions were asked such as "did this happen before, during or after the rain season"? If after this still no date could be established, an event was registered on the 15th day of the month in which it most likely took place. The latter results in a "heaping effect" of events on the 15th of each month, i.e. lots of deaths, births and migrations are attributed to the 15th of each month. It accounts for approx. a third of all deaths in a month (with the average number of deaths per day being approx. 2).

There are several possible solutions we will, together with a statistician, be looking into, including using an error measurement model. These are more complex solutions that we will consider for publication of the research in the long-term.

However, in the short-term, as part of the Master's dissertation for which I am doing this, I am looking to linear interpolation as one option, and as another option running a heaping day indicator variable (with 12 * 14 levels for each month of each year) as a covariate in the regression model. I am aware that these solutions are probably suboptimal, but the time frame is too short to be doing more extensive modelling (given I am new to all of this).

**So here is my question:**

When interpolating deaths between the 14th and the 16th of each month (to remove heaping on the 15th), should I interpolate the other variables as well (births and inward and outward migrations which are also heaped on the 15th), given that these result in change in the population size? My worry is that this leads to a large discrepancy with the real population size which will be approx. 15,000 smaller then when population change is not interpolated.

Or should I just ignore any changes in population size, given that the number of deaths is orders of magnitude smaller than the population size? My worry about this option is that there will be monthly jumps in the population size.

I am new to all this (don't have a degree in statistics), so an explanation in the simplest terms would be appreciated. An explanation pitched at the level of a 15-year old (if at all possible) would be most appreciated!

EDIT: below are two plots of mortality by day for a period of three months and six months respectively:

[image: mortality time series jan-march 2004]

[image: mortality time series jan-jun 2004]

EDIT: a 2-month sample of the data is listed below. All figures are absolute numbers, i.e. death = number of individuals who died.

Variable description: img = inward migration, omg=outward migration, pchange is change in population size , psize = population size (all as absolute number of individuals), wday = day of the week (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday), mday = day of the month, yday = day of the year, week = weeknumber (running from 00-53).

$$
\begin{array}{lllllrlllllll}
\text {date} & \text{birth} & \text{death} & \text{img}& \text{omg}& \text{pchange}& \text{psize}& \text{wday} & \text{mday}& \text{yday}& \text{week}& \text{month}& \text{year}\\
2004-02-01  &   6  &   1 & 14 & 7 &       12 &   73689 &      0 &       1 &     32 &   5 &    2 & 2004 \\
2004-02-02  &   5  &   2 & 6  &11  &      -2 &  73687  &     1  &      2  &    33  &  5  &   2  &2004 \\
2004-02-03  &   3  &   2 & 13  &14   &      0 &  73687 &      2 &       3 &     34 &   5  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-04  &   3  &   2 & 10  &13   &     -2 &  73685 &      3 &       4 &     35 &   5  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-05  &   2  &   2 & 12  &11   &      1 &  73686 &      4 &       5 &     36 &   5  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-06  &   3  &   2 &  7  &16   &     -8 &  73678 &      5 &       6 &     37 &   5  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-07  &   4  &   1 &  9  & 9   &      3 &  73681 &      6 &       7 &     38 &   5  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-08  &   4  &   2 &  3  & 7   &     -2 &  73679 &      0 &       8 &     39 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-09  &   5  &   1 &  5  & 5   &      4 &  73683 &      1 &       9 &     40 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-10  &   2  &   6 & 14  &15   &     -5 &  73678 &      2 &      10 &     41 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-11  &   7  &   4 & 11  & 6   &      8 &  73686 &      3 &      11 &     42 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-12  &   3  &   2 &  9  & 9   &      1 &  73687 &      4 &      12 &     43 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-13  &   4  &   1 &  5  &10   &     -2 &  73685 &      5 &      13 &     44 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-14  &   3  &   0 &  4  &10   &     -3 &  73682 &      6 &      14 &     45 &   6  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-15  &   3  &  16 &269 &287   &    -31 &  73651 &      0 &      15 &     46 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-16  &   3  &   1 &  5 &  9   &     -2 &  73649 &      1 &      16 &     47 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-17  &   7  &   0 &  4 & 10   &      1 &  73650 &      2 &      17 &     48 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-18  &   2  &   0 & 18 & 22   &     -2 &  73648 &      3 &      18 &     49 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-19  &   8  &   4 & 10 &  4   &     10 &  73658 &      4 &      19 &     50 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-20  &   2  &   1 & 10 & 21   &    -10 &  73648 &      5 &      20 &     51 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-21  &   3  &   3 & 13 &  6   &      7 &  73655 &      6 &      21 &     52 &   7  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-22  &   4  &   1 & 12 & 16   &     -1 &  73654 &      0 &      22 &     53 &   8  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-23  &   4  &   4 &  4 &  6   &     -2 &  73652 &      1 &      23 &     54 &   8  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-24  &   2  &   2 &  2 &  9   &     -7 &  73645 &      2 &      24 &     55 &   8  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-25  &   3  &   2 & 13 & 20   &     -6 &  73639 &      3 &      25 &     56 &   8  &   2 &2004  \\
2004-02-26  &   7  &   0 &  8 &  7   &      8 &  73647 &      4 &      26 &     57 &   8  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-27  &   3  &   2 &  1 &  6   &     -4 &  73643 &      5 &      27 &     58 &   8  &   2 &2004  \\
2004-02-28  &   5  &   2 &  9 &  6   &      6 &  73649 &      6 &      28 &     59 &   8  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-02-29  &   3  &   4 & 12 &  5   &      6 &  73655 &      0 &      29 &     60 &   9  &   2 &2004 \\
2004-03-01  &   4  &   0 &  6 &  8   &      2 &  73657 &      1 &       1 &     61 &   9  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-02  &   3  &   1 &  7 &  9   &      0 &  73657 &      2 &       2 &     62 &   9  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-03  &   3  &   3 &  7 &  9   &     -2 &  73655 &      3 &       3 &     63 &   9  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-04  &   1  &   2 &  1 &  7   &     -7 &  73648 &      4 &       4 &     64 &   9  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-05  &   5  &   1 & 11 & 12   &      3 &  73651 &      5 &       5 &     65 &   9  &  3 &2004 \\
2004-03-06  &   5  &   2 &  9 &  3   &      9 &  73660 &      6 &       6 &     66 &   9  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-07  &   5  &   3 &  6 & 17   &     -9 &  73651 &      0 &       7 &     67 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-08  &   8  &   2 &  4 &  7   &      3 &  73654 &      1 &       8 &     68 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-09  &   5  &   3 &  1 & 12   &     -9 &  73645 &      2 &       9 &     69 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-10  &   4  &   2 & 10 & 16   &     -4 & 73641  &     3  &     10  &    70  & 10   &  3 &2004 \\
2004-03-11  &   5  &   0 &  2 &  4   &      3 &  73644 &      4 &      11 &     71 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-12  &   3  &   2 &  4 &  9   &     -4 &  73640  &     5 &      12 &     72 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-13  &   3  &   3 &  7 &  6   &      1 &  73641  &     6 &      13 &     73 &  10  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-14  &   3  &   2 &  5 &  3   &      3 &  73644  &     0 &      14 &     74 &  11  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-15  &   7  &  21 & 230 & 347 &     -131 & 73513 &     1 &       15&      75&   11 &    3 &2004 \\
2004-03-16  &   1  &   3 &  9 &  8   &     -1 &  73512  &     2 &      16 &     76 &  11  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-17  &   6  &   3 &  6 &  5   &      4 &  73516  &     3 &      17 &     77 &  11  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-18  &   6  &   2 & 10 & 12   &      2 &  73518  &     4 &     18  &    78  & 11   &  3 &2004 \\
2004-03-19  &   3  &   5 &  8 &  4   &      2 &  73520  &     5 &      19 &     79 &  11  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-20  &   8  &   2 & 15 & 26   &     -5 &  73515  &     6 &      20 &     80 &  11  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-21  &   2  &   1 &  2 &  5   &     -2 &  73513  &     0 &      21 &     81 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-22  &   6  &   3 &  3 &  4   &      2 & 73515   &    1  &     22  &    82  & 12   &  3 &2004 \\
2004-03-23  &   7  &   3 &  8 &  6   &      6 &  73521  &     2 &      23 &     83 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-24  &   5  &   1 &  4 &  2   &      6 &  73527  &     3 &      24 &     84 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-25  &  10  &   2 & 21 & 11   &     18 &  73545  &     4 &      25 &     85 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-26  &   4  &   0 &  3 &  6   &      1 &  73546  &     5 &      26 &     86 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-27  &   7  &   2 & 11 &  4   &     12 &  73558  &     6 &      27 &     87 &  12  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-28  &   9  &   0 &  7 &  8   &      8 &  73566  &     0 &      28 &     88 &  13  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-29  &  10  &   4 &  9 &  9   &      6 &  73572  &     1 &      29 &     89 &  13  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-30  &   3  &   0 & 10 &  9   &      4 &  73576  &     2 &      30 &     90 &  13  &   3 &2004 \\
2004-03-31  &   3  &   2 &  3 &  2   &      2 &  73578  &     3 &      31 &     91 &  13  &   3 &2004
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Nice question (+1) and welcome to CV.SE. Would it please be possible to show a month or two of data such that it is clear how much monthly seasonality is there? From what you describe: I would say that if we interpolate the number of deaths between the 14th and 16th we will underestimate the overall number of deaths. It might make sense to do this smoothing and potentially distribute the "missed" number of deaths across the whole (or some days) of the month. (I am also sightly surprised that you don't have an "start of the month" effect.)

Comment: Added 2 months of data. Took several hours to work out how to include a data table but managed in the end :-)  When you refer to monthly seasonality and ask for 2 months of data, are you interested in seasonality *within* each month? Births show very clear seasonality but across several months with 2 peaks per year. Seasonality for deaths v. difficult to see. Am hoping that dealing with heaping makes things clearer. Also just looked up start of month effect. Not clear in the data, perhaps because population is poor, rural and largely subsistence farming. Also thanks for upvote and kind welcome

Comment: (I was mostly refer to a simple plot but I appreciate the enthusiasm!) Yes, we want to ensure that we maintain the overall monthly trend while not removing the reporting artefact.

Comment: @usεr11852 Just added 2 plots of time series of daily number of deaths: one for the first 3 months of 2004, and one for the first 6 months. Different 'resolutions" to show patterns in time.